# Remove countdown from vbscript yes-no Box

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

I have this script that will display a yes-no box with a 30 second countdown, and if the user has not selected an option after the time is up, then the VBScript automatically selects the option **"Yes"** and returns to a Batch Script.

How do I remove the countdown part from the script, so that it will not default to **"Yes"**, but instead wait until input is given.

Many Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell, retCode
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

retCode = oShell.Popup("Place your question here?", 30, "Title", 4 + 32)

Select Case retCode
case 6, -1
    WScript.quit(0) 'Yes or time-out was chosen
case 7
    WScript.quit(1) 'No was chosen
End Select
```

vbscript taken from http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/138818-vbscript-msgbox-with-auto-select-countdown-and-batch-script-input/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the answer, for more reference:
[WScript.Shell.Popup](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_popup.html)

```
Dim oShell, retCode
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

retCode = oShell.Popup("Place your question here?", 0, "Title", 4 + 32)

Select Case retCode
case 6, -1
WScript.quit(0) 'Yes or time-out was chosen
case 7
WScript.quit(1) 'No was chosen
End Select`
```